# How to run the same SSIS package multiple times with different configurations

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Due to these awesome ["Behavior Changes to Integration Services Features in SQL Server 2008 R2"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500430%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), is there a way in SQL Server 2008

1) to run the same SSIS package more than once with different configurations

2) while still enabling configurations in design time in BIDS for testing

Basically in 2005, I could create SSIS package, enable configurations in BIDS for testing, and once tested deploy the package to server and run it 3 times using SQL agent with 3 different confogurations.

How can I do that in 2008 or I would have to disable configurations in BIDS before deployment? The problem is if developer will forget to disable them in BIDS, design time configurations will always be used instead of specified ones.

Answer (score 1):

why cant you run the package 3 times?

Just run dtexec with  /config  and Specify a configuration file to extract values from

Or you can create a sql job with 3 steps and on each step run the same package informing different config files on the configurations tab.

I really don't see the problem. "Package" and "config file" are two separate things. Inside BIDS, if you disable configurations, and run the package, it wont read any config file, of course, but if you enable, it will read the values from the config (file or server or whatever) and use them even if you have different values set on the package.

So, why cant the developers work with the configurations enabled and have the values the need set on the config files?

EDIT:

I think you missunderstood. From the page you posted:

> 1- The utility first applies the design-time configurations.

- that means, read the configurations on the config file

> 2 - The utility then applies the run-time options that you specified on
>   the command line when you started the utility.

-that means, things like setting a variable values using the /set option on dtexec

> 3- Finally, the utility reloads and reapplies the design-time
>   configurations.

that means, reload the configurations on the config file

that's why you read in several places that in SQL Server 2008, you cannot use /Set option to override values that are also set by a configuration.

It doesn't actually mean you cant, it means that the values on the config file will prevail over any value set by command line.

No worries, at no moment the values set in BIDS will overwrite the ones you set on your config files.

Comment: yes, it will work if you disable them in BIDS - the only problem you need to remember to do that. If you forget, config file specified in SQL agent job will never overwrite values in SSIS package - this was behavior change i mentioned above in my questions from 2005 to 2008.

Comment: i think i got it right especially because i actually tested this :) Let me explain on example. We have package aaa.dtsx. When you open it in BIDS, configurations are enables and it uses config file named dev.dtsx config that sets connections and some variables. We deploy it then to production SQL server and use dtexec to run it three times - with config prod_a.dtconfig, then prod_b and then prod_c - everytime package will use different connections and settings. While it works perfect in 2005, it does not work in 2008 - our ssis package always picks values from config dev.dtsx.

Comment: the only case when values from configs passed to dtexec are not overwritten by design time config, when they are not set by design time config.